# Navigation bar error

Tags: ios, swift, label, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I've embed in the navigation bar in app, everything work good, except when entering a view where I have set up the navigation bar programmatically (segue to settings, reset function).

It shows just the custom navigation bar, which is ok, but if I implement a custom back button, the whole app has the same navigation bar as problematic one (now it shows the reset and settings button everywhere).

Is there a way to make the navigation bar custom only to that specific view?

Part of the code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    //Add gesture to MainLabel
    let tapLabel: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(resetTime))
    tapLabel.delegate = self
    mainLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mainLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapLabel)

    //Add gesture to UINavigationBar title
    let tapTitle: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(resetTime))
    tapTitle.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.titleView = resetLabel
    self.navigationItem.titleView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.navigationItem.titleView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapTitle)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can hide navigation button on viewDidDisappear of a viewController in which you want custom navigation bar and in viewDidAppear unhide buttons which you need.